# Hardware for adjustable timer with intermittent vibration and buzzer

Tags: embedded-systems

What can I specifically use for a push button adjustable timer that can be programmed to interact with intermittent vibration and a buzzer at the end of the loop?

Is there already something embedded out there? If not, I am willing to build it. But I don't have any programming or hardware knowledge,  only basic circuit knowledge.  I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction to begin the learning process.